# solving without a calculator: 2-4*x*arctan(x) = 0.

Tags: calculus

I was doing some review problems and one of them is find the points of inflection of $\arctan (x)$.  I found the second derivative, but was not able solve the problem.  The part of the problem I could not solve is in the title.

> $2 -4x\arctan (x) = 0$

I get $\frac{1}{2} = x\arctan(x)$

This is where I get lost.

Comment: What topic are you reviewing? Root approximation by newton-raphson?

Comment: @CalvinLin inverse trig functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, we have that

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2} = (1 + x^2)^{-1}$$

Hence the second derivative is $$f''(x) = -(1 + x^2)^{-2} \cdot 2x = \frac{-2x}{(1 + x^2)^2}$$

This is zero if and only if $x = 0$.

---

Actually solving $2x\arctan{x} = 1$ by hand is difficult, since the solution is [not very pleasant](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x+arctan+x+%3D+1). I doubt there's any meaningful closed form.

Comment: why is it difficult?

Answer (score 2):

As mentiones by T. Bongers, the solution of this equation is not pleasant. However, there are things which can be done : if you look at the plot of the function, you can identify that there is one root which is "close" to x = 1. Then, we can build a Taylor series around this point where almost everything is simple. Using f[x] = 2 - 4 x Arctan[x], for x = 1, we have f[1] = 2 - Pi, f'[1] = -2 - Pi, f''[1] = -2. Then, around x = 1, the function can be approximated by g[x] = (2 - Pi) - (2 + Pi) (x - 1) + (x - 1)^2. So, we have a quadratic equation in (x - 1) and the solution of g[x] = 0 corresponds to x = (Sqrt[Pi^2 + 12] - Pi] / 2 that is to say x = 0.767451 while the exact solution of f[x] = 0 corresponds to x = 0.765379.
We can do simpler limitng the development to the first order expansion. In such a case the solution is x = 1 + (2 - Pi) / (2 + Pi) = 4 / (2 + Pi). Pi being close to 3, then x = 0.8 is a reasonable value.